# php beginner, need some explanation?

Tags: php

Looking at the code below I know that we have an array `$r`. The for loop evaluates to `true` and it goes to the `rand` function. The `rand` function generates a number between 0 and 100,000.
Then the `if`-statement checks to see if the number generated is less than or equal to 10.

The final part is what is confusing me, because I think if the number generated is less than 10 then it adds a 1 to it.

Can someone please explain this code. Thank you.

```
<?php
$r = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
for ($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
    $n = rand(0,100000);
    if ($n<=10) {
        $r[$n]++;
    }
}
print_r($r); 
?>
```

Comment: do summat with the indentation.

Comment: you are counting the digits from 0-10 in generation of rand upto 100000

Answer (score 0):

It adds one to the array element corresponding to the number (0 through 10) given by each rand that is less than or equal to 10.

Basically what you are seeing is a demonstration of a random number distribution.  The program will show you how many hits you get on each of the first 11 numbers in the distribution, rather than all of them (which would be quite a large array).

In a perfectly equal distribution, you would get 1 in each array element.  But since we are dealing with random numbers, the actual result will usually be different.

Comment: Can you please confirm this?  it generates a number between 0 and 100,000. If that number is less than or equal to 10 then it adds a 1 to that number. So it lets says in its first iteration it generates the number 7. Array element 8 is then updated with the number 8?

Comment: Array element 8 is incremented.  So if it had a zero in it before, now it has a 1.

Comment: In another example i am looking, the code has a .=, what does .= mean?

Comment: That's a string operator.  You can find out more about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

" I think if the number generated is less than 10 then it adds a 1 to it."

No it **DO NOT** add 1 to **generated** number which id `$n`, but it **DOES** add 1 to `$r` array element with index `$n`.

For example if in first loop iteration you will get `$n = 4` then `$r` array will look like this:

```
$r = array(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

This is because `$r[$n]++;` in this case means `$r[4]++`, which is *increment of `$r[4]`*, which is equal to

```
$r[4]+=1
```

or

```
$r[4] = $r[4]+1
```

`$n` **won't** be changed inside one iteration, but `$r` **is**.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is smaller than 10, then it adds one to the corresponding index in the array `$r`.

It means we count the number of times we had a number smaller than 10, for each of those numbers.

Example: at the end of the loop, `$r[3]` worth the number of time we draw the number `3`